# Data Injection from json file setting to JWT

Tags: c#, authentication, web-applications, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Im trying to insert jwt settings from json file to StartUp.ConfigureServices:

**appsettings.json**

```
  ...
  "jwt": {
    "key": "some_password123TEST!",
    "issuer": "http: //localhost:Port",
    "expiryMinutes": 60
  }
```

**JwtSettings.cs**

```
public class JwtSettings
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Issuer { get; set; }
  public int ExpiryMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 ...
 services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("jwt"));

  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddJwtBearer(o =>
   {
       o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
       {
           // ValidateIssuer = true,
           ValidateIssuer = JwtSettings.Issuer ???
           ...
       });
   }
```

Now how to get my setting from JwtSettings.Issuer?

I tried to add to also add this to `Configure` method:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JwtSettings>();
```

or

```
var test = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JwtSettings>();
app.UseAuthentication(test);
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below codes to get the issue value :

```
services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("jwt"));

services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    var config = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<JwtSettings>>().Value;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = config.Issuer
    };
});
```

Comment: I have implemented the code, tested and seems working ok, thank you for help!